# How to uninstall Eclipse Feature Patch?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am using feature patch to modify Eclipse Code. I install this patch and it works.

But now, I want to uninstall this patch, what should I do ?

I have tried to uninstall it in "Installation Detail" dialog, but this fails with the following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Eclipse RCP 4.23.0.v20220308-0722 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.23.0.v20220308-0722)
Missing requirement: Eclipse RCP 4.23.0.v20220308-0722 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.23.0.v20220308-0722) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui.workbench [3.125.0.v20220308-0722,3.125.0.v20220308-0722]
```

If anyone knows this, can give me some advice, thanks a lot!

Comment: Didn't you get an error message? Anything in the error log?

Comment: The Details in the Uninstall Page:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Eclipse RCP 4.23.0.v20220308-0722 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.23.0.v20220308-0722)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse RCP 4.23.0.v20220308-0722 (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.23.0.v20220308-0722) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui.workbench [3.125.0.v20220308-0722,3.125.0.v20220308-0722]' but it could not be found

Comment: Please improve your question instead of adding comments. It seems in the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ the update site `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03/` and `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/` (one of them should be enough to not get this error).

Comment: @howlger Problem solved, thanks. 
But I still have a doubt that using the above two sites solves the problem, what if I can't connect to the Internet?
sorry for bothering you.

Comment: To uninstall a feature, you need the older stuff that has been replaced by newer stuff of that feature. By default, the things that are no longer needed are deleted during the first restart after the installation. You can disable the deletion of stuff only required in case of uninstalling (`org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler/gcOnStartup=false`), but this has the disadvantage that more disk space is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have **one of** the following **update sites** in the **preferences  *Install/Update > Available Software Sites*** before uninstall it:

- [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03/) or
- [**`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`**](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/)